# Minimizing mean difference in quality of two teams

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose we have 2$n$ players, who we wish to distribute into 2 sports teams of $n$ players each, such that the teams are as equal as possible. To take a simple model, we assign each player a score, and sum these to calculate the team's score.

Let each player's score be a random variable uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. What is the expected value of the difference between the two teams' scores, as a function of $n$? That is,

f($n$) = E(Team A score - Team B score) [after the players have been distributed to make the teams as equal as possible]

Conjecture: f($n$) = 1 / (2^$n$ + 1)

The problem is easy to solve analytically for $n$ = 1. Suppose the first player's score is $x$. The expected value of the difference between the two players is simply 2$x$^2 - 2$x$ + 1. Integrating this function from 0 to 1 yields 1/3, so f(1) = 1/3.

The problem is significantly harder to solve analytically for $n$ = 2. However, it can be calculated roughly using a computer model, and yields f(2) = 1/5.

Can anyone shed light on whether my conjecture is likely to be true, and, if not, what f($n$) may be?

Comment: To make your question clearer for other readers, you should indicate that $f(n)$ is the expected absolute difference between the total scores _after_ the teams are arranged from the $2n$ random scores so as to have the least possible absolute difference.

Comment: As you suggested, except for the case $n=1$, trying to get an exact answer seems like an unwieldy task. I verified your simulation results for $n=2$, yielding a value very, very close to $\frac{1}{5}$, so equality is quite plausible. However, for $n=3$, my simulation, with $10^5$ trials, yields a value of approximately $.095$, which doesn't match your conjectured value of $\frac{1}{9}$.

Comment: @quasi. Thanks, I'll edit my question accordingly. That's helpful info for n=3 ... who knows where this sequence is leading, then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial result . . .

For $n=2$, let the player scores, in ascending order, be given by $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$.

Then the best way to equalize the teams is to arrange them as
$$A = \{x_1,x_4\}$$
$$B = \{x_2,x_3\}$$
In other words, for one team, pair the strongest player with the weakest, and for the other team, pair the two middle-strength players.

Based on that logic, it follows that
\begin{align*}
f(2) &= 24
\int_{x_1=0}^1 
\int_{x_2=x_1}^1
\int_{x_3=x_2}^1
\int_{x_4=x_3}^1
{\Bigl{|}}
(x_1+x_4)-(x_2+x_3)
{\Bigr{|}}
\;dx_4 dx_3 dx_2 dx_1
\\[4pt]
&=(24)\left(\frac{1}{120}\right)\qquad\text{[computed symbolically via Maple]}\\[4pt]
&=\frac{1}{5}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}